How can I use multiple refs for an array of videos to display duration of each video?
I’m currently working on a React project where I pull video URLs from an API and display them using  elements. My goal is to retrieve the duration of each video once the metadata has loaded, but I keep encountering an issue where the duration is logged as NaN.
const videoRefs = useRef<Array<HTMLVideoElement | null>>([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    videoRefs.current.forEach((video, idx) => {
      if (video) {
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (event) => {
          console.log('video', video.duration);
        });
      }
    });
  }, [videosMemo]);    

   <div className="flex overflow-x-auto gap-2 w-full">
          {videosMemo?.map((video, idx) => {
            const fileUrl = videoUrlWithToken(video?.file.id, true);
            return (
              <div
                key={idx}
                className="flex flex-col items-center flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 basis-auto"
              >
                <video
                  src={fileUrl}
                  ref={(el) => {
                    videoRefs.current[idx] = el;
                  }}
                  className="hidden"
                />
                <span>{video.views}</span>
                <span>
                  <p>Duration: {videoRefs.current[idx]?.duration}</p>
                </span>
              </div>
            );
          })}


"...And display them using elements" Does the video elements show any correct duration?
